# Get-Random and Remove from Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, random

Looking to make an array of tasks and then remove them from the array as they are assigned.

So far this works in getting the random task:

```powershell
$Tasks = "a", "b", "c", "d"
$RandomTask = Get-Random $Tasks
```

But when I try to remove it, I get errors:

```powershell
$Tasks = "a", "b", "c", "d"
$RandomTask = Get-Random $Tasks

#Something will assign the task here

$Tasks.Remove("$RandomTask")
```

How do I remove the randomly chosen string from the array?  I keep getting this:

```powershell
Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add or remove items with a normal array after you create it because they have a fixed length.  To do what you want, you need to use the more powerful [`ArrayList` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) found in `System.Collections`:

```powershell
$Tasks = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Tasks.AddRange(("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

Now, you can call the `$Tasks.Remove` method as you were:

```powershell
PS > $Tasks = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
PS > $Tasks.AddRange(("a", "b", "c", "d"))
PS > $Tasks
a
b
c
d
PS > $Tasks.Remove("b")
PS > $Tasks
a
c
d
PS >
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are of a fixed size and can't be modified. You would need to use an `ArrayList`, List or another similar collection to use `Remove()`, `RemoveAt()`, `Add()` etc. Sample:

```
$tasks = [System.Collections.ArrayList]("a", "b", "c", "d")

#Loop through every item in arraylist
1..$tasks.Count | ForEach-Object {
    #Get random task
    $randomtask = Get-Random $tasks.ToArray()

    Write-Host "Random task is: $randomtask"

    #Remove random task
    $tasks.Remove($randomtask)

    #Display remaining tasks
    $tasks
}
Random task is: c
a
b
d
Random task is: d
a
b
Random task is: b
a
Random task is: a
```

I would recommend a generic List because ArrayLists are untyped and deprecated. To use a generic list for string-objects, a few modifications are required:

```
$tasks = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]("a", "b", "c", "d")

#Loop through every item in arraylist
1..$tasks.Count | ForEach-Object {
    #Get random task
    $randomtask = Get-Random $tasks.ToArray()

    Write-Host "Random task is: $randomtask"

    #Remove random task (List's Remove() method returns a bool
    $tasks.Remove($randomtask) | Out-Null

    #Display remaining tasks
    $tasks
}
```

If your objects are of different classes, you could try a `List[object]`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to randomize the tasks, and load them into a `queue`, then use the `.dequeue()` method to return a task and automatically remove it from the queue:

```
$tasklist = 'a','b','c','d'

$taskqueue = [collections.queue]($tasks | Get-Random -Count $tasks.count)

For ( $i=1; $i -le $tasklist.Count; $i++ )
{
$Task = $taskqueue.Dequeue()
Write-Host "Current task: $Task"
Write-Host "Remaining tasks: $taskqueue`n"
}

Current task: c
Remaining tasks: b d a

Current task: b
Remaining tasks: d a

Current task: d
Remaining tasks: a

Current task: a
Remaining tasks:
```